# Kubernetes - service exposed via NodePort not available on all nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I've a nginx service exposed via NodePort. According to the documentation, I should now be able to hit the service on `$NODE_IP:$NODE_PORT` for all my K8 worker IPs. However, I'm able to access the service via curl on only the node that hosts the actual nginx pod. Any idea why?

I did verify using netstat that kube-proxy is listening on $NODE_PORT on all the hosts. Somehow, the request is not being forwarded to the actual pod by kube-proxy.

Comment: You can always reach your services through servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local if you're running kube dns

Comment: @MattRickard - In this case, I am looking to expose the service outside K8 for other non-K8 hosted services to consume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the security group associated with the workers. I had opened only the ports in the `--service-node-port-range`. This was not enough because I was deploying nginx on port 80 and kube-proxy tried to forward the request to the pod's IP on port 80 but was being blocked.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I'm facing a similar issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785402/configure-ingress-kubernetes-accessible-only-on-single-node , could you please provide some suggestions?