# Configure Ingress Kubernetes - accessible only on single node

Tags: kubernetes

I had setup ingress on my Kubernetes Cluster running on VMWAre virtual machines by following everything similar to the specifications here. All the ports are open and accessible.

https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example

My master is x.x.x.10 and nodes are x.x.x.12 and x.x.x.13.

After the creation of ingress/controllers, I need to get the IP where the nginx-controller runs

```
nginx-ingress-rc-kgfmd          1/1       Running   0          21h       172.16.5.5   x.x.x.12
```

so, it usually runs either on x.x.x.12 or x.x.x.13, and then when I do this it hits my web service

curl --resolve  master.federated.fds:80:x.x.x.12 https://master.federated.fds/coffee

where master.federated.fds is the DNS resolvable name of Master.

I need to make it work without the help of IP address and only with the DNS resolvable name or else atleast with any of the node ip's

Eg: http://node2.federated.fds/coffee, when I curl this I get Connection refused error

Updating with specifications

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: coffee-svc
  labels:
    app: coffee
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
#    nodePort: 30080
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: coffee
```

ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: jciamaster.federated.fds
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

nginx ing controller

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-rc
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginxdemos/nginx-ingress:0.8.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
```

I see that the port 80 is listening only on the node where nginx pod runs and not on any other node. Could someone pls let me know how to access the application through all node ip's or thro a url like jciamaster.federated.fds?

Thanks,

Update:

Tried to run with nginx controller as svc as suggested by Marc

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-rc
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginxdemos/nginx-ingress:0.8.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

        # Uncomment the lines below to enable extensive logging and/or customization of
        # NGINX configuration with configmaps
        #args:
         #- -v=3
         #- -nginx-configmaps=default/nginx-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: nginx-ingress-label
  name: nginx-ing-svc
spec:
  ports:
   - port: 80
     targetPort: 80
     protocol: TCP
     name: http
     nodePort: 30000
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    name: nginx-ingress
```

When I hit http://x.x.x.:30000/coffee it just hangs and does nothing.Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: so it seems like  I need to hit  https://dns-of-node-running-nginx-ingress/employee which in this case is x.x.x.12 whereas I had been hitting https://dns-of-master/employee , is it possible to run the ingress, and hit the url simply to access the application instead of finding out the node where nginx-ingress runs, then use its dns name to access the url?

Comment: Folks, any clue on this one?There is not an awful lot of help out there.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose the nginx controller Pod with a NodePort Service, then you can access it on all nodes.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion Marc, but seems like Im missing something if I expose it as a svc

Comment: see this example (you might need to change namespace and selector according to your existing setup): https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/examples/rbac/nginx/nginx-ingress-controller-service.yml
This will expose the nginx controller on all nodes on port 30080.

Comment: This seems like a bug mostly. Refer https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47711

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Was able to get it to work.

Comment: Hi Marc, one more question, could you let me know or point to some materials in which I can loadbalance my application through a single URL or hostname e.g http://jciamaster.federated.fds/employee , http://jciamaster.federated.fds/reward?

Comment: -- just found this, http://hustcat.github.io/bare-metal-lb-for-kube-cluster/  might be this do the trick. I'll try it out